# CSS card flip animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to build an animation where each time a card is clicked the card flips over and reveals the opposite side.  The words on each side of the card will change every time the card is flipped.  The problem I am having is that the front face of my card only is visible on sporadic occasions.  I cannot find any logic to why the front face is normally not visible but occasionally will be visible.

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdammon/ucf6mx1q/

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div id="headerSection">
            <h1>Heard At Prime</h1>
        </div>
        <div id='whiteBlock'>
                <div id='front'>hey</div>
                <div id='back'>hi</div>


        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the flipping logic for the #whiteBlock div:

```
$(document).ready(onReady);

function onReady(){
    $('#whiteBlock').on('click', flipIt)
}

quotesArray=['hey','cool saying','funny thing','hahaha'];

function flipIt() {
    console.log('flip')

    $('#front').empty();
    $('#back').empty();
    let firstQuote= quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotesArray.length)]
    let secondQuote= quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotesArray.length)]
    $('#front').append(firstQuote);
    $('#back').append(secondQuote);
    $('#whiteBlock').toggleClass('flip');


};
```

And the CSS animations:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

section{
    perspective: 500px;
}

#whiteBlock{
    background-color:white;
    height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /* transition: transform .5s;  */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /* position: absolute;
    animation: move 3s linear infinite;  */
}

#whiteBlock:active{
    transform:scale(.97);
    transition: transform .2s
}

#whiteBlock.flip{
    transform:rotateY(180deg)
}

#front{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;   
}


#back{
    position:absolute;   
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`backface-visibility` still requires vendor prefixes. So you'll need `-webkit-backface-visibility` for Chrome and Safari and -moz for Firefox.

With a couple changes this more of less works for me in Safari and should be a good starting point:

```js
$(document).ready(onReady);

function onReady() {
  $('#whiteBlock').on('click', flipIt)
}

let quotesArray = ['hey', 'cool saying', 'funny thing', 'hahaha'];

function flipIt() {
  console.log('flip')

  $('#front').empty();
  $('#back').empty();
  let firstQuote = quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length)]
  let secondQuote = quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length)]
  $('#front').append(firstQuote);
  $('#back').append(secondQuote);
  $('#whiteBlock').toggleClass('flip');
};
```

```css
section {
  perspective: 500px;
}

#whiteBlock {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

#whiteBlock.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

#front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="headerSection">
    <h1>Heard At Prime</h1>
  </div>
  <div id='whiteBlock'>
    <div id='front'>hey</div>
    <div id='back'>hi</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Any idea why the front face is visible for me some of the time but not often.  The back face is always visible